# I have an AWS IAM role that can't be deleted because it's being used by a DynamoDB table that has been gone for a long time

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS IAM role, `AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable` that I can't deleted and now it has a permanent "Deletion failed" label:

[image]

If I go inside there's an error that points to a DynamoDB table:

[image]

That table, `covid_19_test`, was created and destroyed, probably about 333 days ago.

Any ideas?

This is a "Trust relationships" look like:

[image]

Comment: Does the service appear in 'Trust relationships'? Can you delete the trust? You might have to go the support route here.

Comment: What is "Trust relationships"?

Comment: There is a tab on that page entitled Trust relationships.

Comment: @jarmod I added a screenshot of that.

Comment: Assuming you have he necessary IAM permission, typically you would be able to delete the trust relationship but it looks like that’s not available here. I think a support ticket might be your best option at this point.

Comment: I am the root user in the account, so I should have whatever permission is required.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.

I was able to resolve the issue by deregister the Application Auto Scaling associated with AWS DynamoDB via AWS CloudShell.

Get information about Application Auto Scaling associated with AWS DynamoDB

```
aws application-autoscaling describe-scalable-targets --service-namespace dynamodb
```

Deregister an Application Auto Scaling scalable target

```
aws application-autoscaling deregister-scalable-target --service-namespace dynamodb --resource-id <resource-id> --scalable-dimension <scalable-dimension>
```

Deregistering a scalable target deletes the scaling policies and the scheduled actions that are associated with it.

After deregistering the Application Auto Scaling scalable target, deleting the IAM role **AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable** should be possible.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/index.html